# Insert Statement not working for Insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger that executes off the back of a stored procedure, to capture certain data changes and inserts, for audit purposes.
There is a stored procedure that adds rows to table DTA, the trigger is coded to fire from this as such;

```
CREATE TRIGGER [AUDIT_TRACE]
    ON [DTA]
    AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'tmp_inserted')
            DROP TABLE tmp_inserted 
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'tmp_deleted')
            DROP TABLE tmp_deleted 
        SELECT * INTO tmp_inserted from inserted
        SELECT * INTO tmp_deleted from deleted

        INSERT INTO [AUDIT_TRAIL]
        SELECT 
            UpdatedDate
            ,UserName
            ,Name
            ,oldValue
            ,newValue
            ,DATATABLEID
            ,ISNULL(AuthInvNo,'')+ISNULL(invNO,'') as InvoiceNumber
            ,AuthAccount As Product
            ,AuthValue AS Value
            ,QTY
            ,InputScreen
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                i.UpdatedDate as [UpdatedDate]
                ,psn.UserName as [Username]
                ,CONCAT(psn.Firstname,' ',psn.surname) as [Name]
                ,CONVERT(nvarchar(36),i.DataTableId) as [DataTableID]
                ,dtType.Description as [InputScreen]
                ,dtat.Description as [ColumnName]
                ,CONVERT(nvarchar(1000),dtText.Text) as [Entry]
                ,dtavB.Description as OldValue
                ,dtavA.Description as NewValue
            FROM dt
            INNER JOIN inserted i on i.DataTableId = dt.DataTableId
            LEFT JOIN deleted d on d.DataTableId = i.DataTableId
            INNER JOIN dtavA on dtavA.DataTableAttributeValueId = i.DataTableAttributeValueId
                                and dtavA.DataTableAttributeTypeId IN ('23087D97-B96B-4015-9E66-258EE7CAF499','2D5E9D64-A2B6-444D-938A-7D8DD66208E0')-- after
            LEFT JOIN dtavB on dtavB.DataTableAttributeValueId = d.DataTableAttributeValueId
                                and dtavB.DataTableAttributeTypeId IN ('23087D97-B96B-4015-9E66-258EE7CAF499','2D5E9D64-A2B6-444D-938A-7D8DD66208E0')-- before
            INNER JOIN dtText on dtText.DataTableId = i.DataTableId
            INNER JOIN dtType on dtType.DataTableTypeId = dt.DataTableTypeID
            INNER JOIN psn on psn.PersonId = i.UpdatedBy
            INNER JOIN dtat on dtat.DataTableAttributeTypeId = dtText.DataTableAttributeTypeId
        )E
        PIVOT(MAX([ENTRY]) FOR [COLUMNNAME] IN(DEBITCREDIT,AuthValue,QTY,AuthAccount,AuthInvNo,InvNO))as p
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Now the problem is that when inserting data into the DTA table nothing is being inserted into our AUDIT_TRAIL table, but when a row is updated in the DTA table, the outcome is exactly what we expect, oldValue, NewValue and all. As far as my colleagues and I can tell there is nothing wrong with the query, we have used profiler traces and all the sections are executing as they should. When running the code manually to select from the tmp_Inserted and tmp_Deleted tables, so we can see what the values we are dealing with are, there is again no issue. To further complicate things, when the INSERT INTO statement is run on its own then the newly inserted line appears as we would expect.

Comment: You are creating tmp_inserted and tmp_deleted tables and not using them in your trigger.  Is it intended behavior? This may not solve your problem, but you can try to either remove these two tables or use them in the inline INSERT statement.

Comment: @Swapnil The temp tables are solely there to help us debug this problem, they will go when we can get the trigger working. For now they allow us to see the values of inserted and deleted and if need be swap them into the query to check what would be put into the AUDIT_TRAIL table.

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong here. However without any tables it is challenging to really wrap my head around what is going on.

Comment: @SeanLange, while we have tried both with and without the tmp tables and get the same results and getting slightly off topic, I am interested in how concurrency issues could occur, these tables are dropped each time the trigger fires so nothing is going to carry over

Comment: There are multiple JOINs in the insert statement. I suspect they might be filtering the data. Can you replace insert statement with simply selecting from inserted and remove rest of the code.

Comment: @BrandonWhite I deleted my previous comment about concurrency when you stated you were using this just for debugging. But if you drop the table and recreate it you could have concurrency issues with the data because multiple people could be inserting data at the same time. This of course is pretty far off topic from your original post and not relevant as you clarified this is just debugging stuff.

Comment: @Swapnil the trouble is that we have used the tmp_inserted and tmp_deleted tables to prove that the data is not being filtered out. Running the select statement by replacing inserted and deleted with the tmp_ versions will always return a result.

Comment: @BrandonWhite I would like to re phrase. you are inserting data from INSERTED into tmp_inserted without any filter. In order to ensure that data is not filtered, insert data from INSERTED after joining it with all tables in inline  INSERT.     "SELECT I.* INTO tmp_inserted FROM dt JOIN inserted AS  I ON i.DataTableId = dt.DataTableId LEFt JOIN ....etc."

Comment: @Swapnil ah, my apologies, i will check now

Comment: @Swapnil the problem is coming from the fact that DTA, dtavA, dtavB dtType and dtat are being inserted into sequencially and that the trigger is not at the end of the chain. The consequence of this is that, as you said, the data is being filtered out when the trigger is active, yet all of these inserts have concluded when we come back to debug after. Would you like to compose some sort of answer so i can credit you with the solution?

Comment: @BrandonWhite Glad that you found the reason..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to ensure that data is not filtered by the JOINs in insert statement within trigger, insert data from INSERTED by joining it with all tables in inline INSERT.

```
SELECT I.* INTO tmp_inserted
FROM dt
INNER JOIN inserted i on i.DataTableId = dt.DataTableId
LEFT JOIN deleted d etc..
```